# spring boot mvc how to support multiple viewresoler (eg. jsp and freemarker)

Tags: java, spring

I hope my web application support jsp and freemarker both templates.i have read the article at below.
https://spring.io/blog/2013/06/03/content-negotiation-using-views
my code as below. the result is only the jsp template OK.
what wrong with my configration?

#### MvcConfiguration.java

```js
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 @Bean
 public InternalResourceViewResolver getJspViewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
  resolver.setOrder(0);
  return resolver;
 }

 @Bean
 public FreeMarkerViewResolver getFmViewResolver() {
  FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
  resolver.setCache(true);
  resolver.setPrefix("");
  resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
  resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
  resolver.setOrder(1);
  return resolver;
 }
 
 @Bean
   public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() throws IOException, TemplateException {
     FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory factory = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory();
     factory.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:templates");
     factory.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
     FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
     result.setConfiguration(factory.createConfiguration());
     return result;
   } 
 

 @Bean
 public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(
   ContentNegotiationManager manager) {
  List<ViewResolver> resolvers = new ArrayList<ViewResolver>();
  resolvers.add(getJspViewResolver());
  resolvers.add(getFmViewResolver());

  ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
  resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
  resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
  return resolver;
 }
}
```

#### TestController.java

```js
@Controller
public class TestController {

 @RequestMapping("/hello")
 public String jspView() {
  return "hello";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping("/fm")
 public String freemarkerView() {
  return "fm";
 }
 
}
```

#### hello.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
 out.println("hello jsp");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

#### fm.ftl

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<body>
  hello freemarker
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: change the order of your view resolvers.

Comment: Thank you very much. but why? what is the reason?is the InternalResourceViewResolver msut at the last?

Comment: The `FreeMarkerViewResolver` does a check if a certain view exists or not, if not it will return `null`, this will lead to consulting the next one the `InternalResourceViewResolver` this one doesn't do a check and always returns a view (url) to render regardless if it exists or not. Hence if you have the `InternalResourceViewResolver` first your `FreeMarkerViewResolver` would never be consulted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ViewResolver`s are all consulted in a chain, until one of them returns a `View` to render ([javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ViewResolver.html#resolveViewName-java.lang.String-java.util.Locale-)).

However the [`InternalResourceViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceViewResolver.html) is a little different then other `ViewResolver` implementations, it simply constructs an URL (using the `prefix` and `suffix`) and returns an `View` which will in turn forward the request to this URL`. Hence it will *always* return a`View` instance.

Now when you have multiple `ViewResolver`s make sure the `InternalResourceViewResolver` is always the last in the chain (as also mentioned in the javadocs of said class). If you don't and it is the first your whole chain won't be consulted.

To fix your problem just switch the order of the `ViewResolver`s and that way you will have both FreeMarker and JSP views working.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer (at least to someone not an expert in these technologies).  However the question could use some work -- do you think you could improve it to be more searchable for others with this problem, so they can find your answer?